# Return Boolean if element of first array is in element of second nested array

Tags: javascript, search, ecmascript-6, filter

I have two different types of arrays
`firstArrayObject = [{name: "sample", number: 23}, {name: "sample2", number: 25}]`.

The second object looks like this `secondObject = {someAttribute: bla, numbers: [23, 26, 27, 28}`

Now i want to check if at least one of the provided `number` fields of the `firstArrayObject` is **not** part of the `secondObject`'s `numbers` Array. If it is not part, stop the search progress and return true. In the provided example it should return true, because "25" is not part of `secondObject.numbers`

Im struggling with all the different methods es6 provides like includes, filter, some.

Hopefully anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `some`:

```
const result = firstArrayObject.some(
    ({number}) => !secondObject.numbers.includes(number)
);
```

```js
const firstArrayObject = [{name: "sample", number: 23}, {name: "sample2", number: 25}];
const secondObject = {someAttribute: "bla", numbers: [23, 26, 27, 28]};

const result = firstArrayObject.some(({number}) => !secondObject.numbers.includes(number));

console.log(result);
```

That says: "Do some (any) of `firstArrayObject`'s elements match the condition '`number` is not included in the array `secondObject.numbers'?"

I used destructuring there, but you don't have to:

```
const result = firstArrayObject.some(
    (element) => !secondObject.numbers.includes(element.number)
);
```

If `secondObject.numbers` were a very larger array, you might start out by making a `Set` of the known numbers, because the `has` function of a `Set` is required (by the JavaScript specification) to have better performance than the linear lookup time of `includes`:

```
const numbers = new Set(secondObject.numbers);
const result = firstArrayObject.some(
    ({number}) => !numbers.has(number)
);
```

```js
const firstArrayObject = [{name: "sample", number: 23}, {name: "sample2", number: 25}];
const secondObject = {someAttribute: "bla", numbers: [23, 26, 27, 28]};

const numbers = new Set(secondObject.numbers);
const result = firstArrayObject.some(
    ({number}) => !numbers.has(number)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!!
Used forEach and includes function of array.
A good [resource](https://javascript.info/array-methods) to learn javascript array functions.

```
var answer = false;
const firstArrayObject = [{name: "sample", number: 23}, {name: "sample2", number: 25}];

const secondObject = {someAttribute: "bla", numbers: [23, 26, 27, 28]};

function func(obj) {
    if(!secondObject.numbers.includes(obj.number)) answer = true;
}

firstArrayObject.forEach(func);
console.log(answer)
```

Edit: func can be created as the forEach parameter itself, although the above implementation might make it more readable for beginners.